# Spring saml redirects the request to http

Tags: spring-saml

I am using the spring saml extension with Apache 2.2 + Tomcat 7.0 + OKTA(IdP). The securityContext.xml looks as follows:

MetadataGeneratorFilter:

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <property name="entityBaseURL" value="https://myapp.com/api"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

ContextProvider:

```
<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderLB">
    <property name="scheme" value="https"/>
    <property name="serverName" value="myapp.com"/>
    <property name="serverPort" value="443"/>
    <property name="includeServerPortInRequestURL" value="false"/>
    <property name="contextPath" value="/api"/>
    <property name="storageFactory">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.storage.EmptyStorageFactory"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I use the following URL which triggers the SP initiated login.

```
https://myapp.com/api/welcome.html
```

After authentication is complete, the browser gets redirected to HTTP instead of HTTPS.

```
 http://myapp.com/api/welcome.html
```

I don't know why the request gets redirected to HTTP. Please help.

Thanks

Nara

HTTP Requests Dump:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mYh-EhDjxMixzZ8krhOg_2fjpTaTu7fuST_nIXAMeVY/edit?usp=sharing

In OKTA, created a SAML 2.0 app with following metadata:

```
    Single Sign On URL => https://myapp.com/api/saml/SSO
    Recipient URL => https://myapp.com/api/saml/SSO
    Destination URL => https://myapp.com/api/saml/SSO
    Audience Restriction => https://myapp.com/api/saml/metadata
    Default Relay State => https://myapp.com/dashboard.html
    Name ID Format => Unspecified
    Response => Signed
    Assertion Signature => Signed
    Signature Algorithm => RSA_SHA256
    Digest Algorithm => SHA256
    Assertion Encryption => Unencrypted
    SAML Single Logout => Disabled
    authnContextClassRef => PasswordProtectedTransport
    Request Compression => Uncompressed
    Honor Force Authentication => Yes
    SAML Issuer ID => http://www.okta.com/${org.externalKey}
```

Spring Config:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/16iDLcBuwvQ23-mKMFybPfxdIyvqCBi5sbYePgUjl0p4/edit?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Please make a dump of HTTP requests between IDP and SP + metadata you imported to IDP and add it to the question.

Comment: Vladimir: Appreciate your repose. Please find above the additional data as requested.

Comment: Okta is responding to the correct address "https://myapp.com/api/saml/SSO", so the issue is somewhere in Spring configuration. Could you please post complete Spring configs?

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. Please find the link for spring config.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't see the real reason, your configuration looks ok, but please try replacing the current `successRedirectHandler` with the following (replace URL with your own of course) and see if the issue goes away:

```
<bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="https://yourapp.com/welcome.jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. 1) Set the defaultTargetUrl as above. Tried the /saml/login. After authentication, the browser goes into a redirect loop between /welcome.jsp, https://myokta.com/app/dev400736_devserver_1/exk4e58o6u7P4jjrh0h7/sso/saml, and /saml/SSO. 2) Start with /welcome.jsp(instead of /saml/login). The redirect goes to http://.../welcome.jsp and browser shows a connection reset error. After that, I change the scheme to https . Then, I can open the page normally.

Comment: Vladimir, One more question...the tomcat's server.xml has the following connector.    <Connector port="18200" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="40000" proxyName="myapp.com" proxyPort="80"/>. Can it be source of the redirection problem?

Comment: After adding the secure attribute to connector, the redirection happens correctly.

Comment: Just to add for those still having issues.  In addition to this fix, I also had to set the `setAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl` to true for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your IDP is configured with proper metadata XML with https assertion end points.

```
<md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="**https**://../saml/SSO" index="0" isDefault="true" />
<md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="**https**://.../saml/SSO" index="1" />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure that your answer is phrased *as an answer*, not as a question. Also, XML tags are invisible unless you put them in a code block, as I've done here.