# Multiple AssertionConsumerService in SP with differend 2nd level domains

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I am implementing a multitenant application with the spring security saml extention.

I have a Service Provider (SP) for each tenant.
All SPs runs on the same server exposed with SP-specific 2nd level domain:

- **sp1**.myapp.com/myapi/**1**/
- **sp1**.myapp.com/myapi/**2**/

In each SP metadata file I have configured the tenant-specific AssertionConsumerService.

When I test the SSO Login, I get a KO on SP side when it gets the response of the Identity Provider (IDP).
On Log side i see only:

```
ERROR [BaseSAMLMessageDecoder] SAML message intended destination endpoint 'https://sp1.myapp.com/myapi/saml/SSO' did not match the recipient endpoint 'https://default.myapp.com/myapi/saml/SSO'
```

Where the 'https://default.myapp.com/myapi/saml/SSO' is the URL set as *serverName* of the *load balancer context provider*:

```xml
<bean id="lbContextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderLB" init-method="afterPropertiesSet">
    <property name="metadata"    ref="metadata" />
    <property name="keyManager"  ref="keyManager" />
    <property name="scheme"      value="https" />
    <property name="serverName"  value="default.myapp.com" />
    <property name="contextPath" value="/myapi" />
    <property name="serverPort"  value="443" />
    <property name="includeServerPortInRequestURL" value="true" />
</bean>
```

### Question

In the [docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/spring-security-saml-reference.pdf) I see that

> Service provider can now define multiple assertion consumer endpoints with same binding

- How can I configure it?
- Does it conflict with load balancer context provider?
- Can I provide multiple AssertionConsumerService with different 2nd level domains without reproduction this conflict?

### I already tested:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580034/spring-security-saml-configuration-error-with-okta) seems to be fixed with the LB, but anyone knows if I can provide multiple serverName to load balancer context provider (maybe with a dynamic pick)?
- Disable the checking of the InResponseToField as suggested at [ch.13 docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-troubleshooting.html#d5e1933) and for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63901706/getting-https-localhost-myapp-saml-sso-redirection-throws-404-error-spring-m) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45206873/samlexception-inresponsetofield-of-the-response-doesnt-correspond-to-sent-mess).
- Configure the defaultTargetUrl of the successRedirectHandler (where I am using a custom superclass of org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler) as suggested  for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308170/spring-saml-redirects-the-request-to-http). In addition this solution is not multitenant.

```xml
<bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.MySamlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" 
                            init-method="afterPropertiesSet">
    <property name="contextPath" value="/myapi" />
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="https://default.myapp.com/myapi/saml/SSO"/>
    <property name="requireProxyWrapping" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: SAML metadata for an SP lists its ACS urls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567112/more-than-one-acs-url

Comment: @codebrane , additional AssertionConsumerService in the SP configuration do not solve the conflict with the load balancer

Comment: updated with new tests and more plain examples

Answer (score 0):

Customize SAMLContextProviderLB by extending SamlContextProviderLB.

In custom class, add constructor and initialize with default values.

Override getLocalAndPeerEntity/getLocalEntity/populateLocalEntityId. In each of this method set lbDomain based on domain in requestURL.

above approach worked for me.